# C# Tasks sums variable

Tags: c#, task

I have the following tasks, they share the sum variable and at the end the sum should be 9, but I get 3.  Can you please help me how to fix it.  Many thanks.

```
int sum = 0;
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    sum = sum + Computation();
});
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    sum = sum + Computation();
});
Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    sum = sum + Computation();
});

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
Console.WriteLine($"The sum is {sum}");

private static int Computation()
{
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for Computation() please.

Comment: Why are you using tasks here?

Comment: No thread synchronisation logic here? Can you sync your threads to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're writing the same field from multiple threads at the same time.

Use Interlocked.Add from System.Threading, which will prevent each thread from writing the variable at the same exact moment.

```
int sum = 0;
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     Interlocked.Add(ref sum,Computation());
});
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     Interlocked.Add(ref sum,Computation());
});
Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     Interlocked.Add(ref sum,Computation());
});

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
Console.WriteLine($"The sum is {sum}");
```

Comment: Ok, it works but I have to add ref: Interlocked.Add(ref sum, Computation());

Comment: You need a `ref` on those calls. Worth noting that with the original, the result *could* have ended up being 9, or possibly 6. Things which can sometimes work are worse than those that will reliably fail and hence get fixed.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you think it could be improved?

Comment: Interlocked methods provide a quick and easy way to work integers from multiple threads without worrying too much about threading. If you want to work with something more complex than integers, take a look at the [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), with that you can make sure that the current thread is the only one using that object.

Comment: There are also predefined collections for multi-thread work: [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx), these work much like your normal list / hashset / queue except with support for atomic operations.

Answer (score 0):

You never tell your code to wait until task 't1' is finished until you start 't2', etc, so everything executes in parallel. Each thread reads the value in "sum" (initially 0) and adds 3. So 0+3 = 3. After that it then writes back the 3. So the code does exactly you programmed it to do.
Galister explained how you could add locks (one side note on this comments: operations in a computer almost never happen at *exactly* the same moment ;) )

Comment: I am trying to sum in parallel.

Comment: `operations in a computer almost never happen at exactly the same moment ` If you have a single core CPU, kinda.  Almost nobody does these days though.  And even on a single core CPU, operations are not performed atomically, the composite operations are themselves interwoven with each other, so you can't really say that one happens "before" or "after" another.

Comment: @Dino:
How did you have in mind how that works? How would you add 3 numbers at the same time on paper? What you are doing in your code is the equivalent of telling three people to add a number (3) to another number, but they do not know what the others are doing. So they only know the 'other number' to be the initial number (0).

Comment: @servy: still on a multi-core multi-thread cpu, operations will almost never happen EXACTLY at the same time.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Two operations might not start and finish together at exactly the same time. Two operations are both going to be making progress at EXACTLY the same time (at pretty much all times).

Comment: @DinoOrazio of course it is, but that example also forms the base of your question. And the idea behind multiple threads accessing a common external variable is the same. That's way semaphores, mutexes and (spin)locks are required.

Answer (score 0):

`Interlocked` class are great when atomic operations are required but if you care about performance consider combine it with `Thread Local Storage (TLS)`.

The Parallel.For has a unique overloads for them, [documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For__1_System_Int64_System_Int64_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Func___0__System_Func_System_Int64_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState___0___0__System_Action___0__).

Example:

```
int sum = 0;
Parallel.For(1, 3,
    () => 0, //The type of the thread-local data.
    (x, state, tls) => // The delegate that is invoked once per iteration.
    {
        tls += x;
        return tls;
    }, 
    partial => //The delegate that performs a final action on the local state of each task.
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref sum, partial);
    });
```

Do consider that for a small loops, it does not matter, and there will be no actual difference between using the `Thread Local Storage` and `Interlocked. For big loops, it will make a difference, using lock in big loops can cause serious overhead ([blog](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/)):

> This will potentially add a huge amount of overhead to our
>   calculation.  Since we can potentially block while waiting on the lock
>   for every single iteration, we will most likely slow this down to
>   where it is actually quite a bit slower than our serial
>   implementation.  The problem is the lock statement – any time you use
>   lock(object), you’re almost assuring reduced performance in a parallel
>   situation.   When parallelizing a routine, try to avoid locks.

The idea is to reduce the acquire a lock on the `sum` variable, note that every task is trying to acquire a lock it in every single point of time. Using the `Thread Local Storage` making the `sum` variable  to be locked as much only as the number of threads.

> instead of synchronizing once per element (potentially millions of
>   times), you’ll only have to synchronize once per thread